# Numpy divide row by row sum in a 3D matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have a 3D NumPy array with shape [2,2,3]
`x=np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])`

```
In [5]: x
Out[5]:
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

The sum of the matrix across the last dimension is

```
In [4]: x.sum(axis=2)
Out[4]:
array([[ 6, 15],
       [ 6, 15]])
```

I want to divide x by `x.sum(axis=2)` in such a way that I get the output as

```
array([[[1, 2, 3]/6,
        [4, 5, 6]/15],

       [[1, 2, 3]/6,
        [4, 5, 6]/15]])
```

I tried using a for loop using the following method

```
In [6]: for y in x:
   ...:     print(y/y.sum(axis=1)[:,None])
   ...:
[[0.16666667 0.33333333 0.5       ]
 [0.26666667 0.33333333 0.4       ]]
[[0.16666667 0.33333333 0.5       ]
 [0.26666667 0.33333333 0.4       ]]
```

I wanted a more efficient and vectorised way to implement this.

Comment: You almost got it, use `x / x.sum(axis=2)[...,None]` instead and you can get rid of the loop.